# How to Load an external web page inside my one and hide some content (avoiding cross site problems)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I need to incorporate in my web application some content from an external dynamic web page on which I have no control.

Then I need to filter some of the content of this page or to hide it for presenting only the relevant part that is interesting for my use.

I need also that the scripts on the external page are still working on the source site of the loaded content without cross-site protection.

Is all that possible? How can I do it? Any code example, please?

I suppose that this can be made with JS on client side .
I work on back side and these themes are quite extraneous to me, please don't blame me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No, it is not possible.

Browser [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is designed to prevent malicious websites from doing **evil**.

Same-origin Policy restricts JavaScript network access to **prevent evil**.

Same-origin Policy also restricts script API Access to **prevent evil**.

From the Docs:

> JavaScript APIs like [iframe.contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow), [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent), [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), and [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) allow documents to directly reference each other. When two documents do not have the same origin, these references provide very limited access to [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) and [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) objects.
>
> To communicate between documents from different origins, use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).
>
> — [MDN Web Security Reference - Cross-origin script API access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access)

One can not use [`<iframe>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) as a way to "avoid cross site problems". The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) was created to protect users from evil web pages.